# Not able to display image and text side by side using float

Tags: c#, html, css

I want to display image and text side by side (image on the left and text on the right(which is ordered using ).

I achieved this in .html page in visual studio

For image div I gave `float: left` and for text div I gave `float:right`

I want to achieve the same by passing the html page code to a string variable and displaying the ouput in WebBrowser.

Eg:

```
string html= @"<div style=""float:left"">
        <img src=""smiley.jpg"" alt=""smiley"" />
        <div style=""float:right;font-family:Calibri"">
            <h2>Dispalying Image and text</h2>           
        </div>
    </div>"

webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

But here, the image and text is not displayed side by side instead the text is displayed in the next line.
Float:right is not working as expected here. How to resolve this?

Comment: divs automatically do a line break.  I suggest putting the image inside the text div, or changing the text div to a span instead

Comment: I've got the expected output by placing image in one div and text in one div and both the div in one div. It worked:)
Like,
<div>
<div><img></div>
<div>text</div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` is an inline element, and `<div>` and `<h2>` are block elements, you are mixing both together. And also, you can't set "float" to inline element.

Maybe you can try to put img inside, like this:

```
<div>
    <div style=""font-family:Calibri"">
        <h2>
            <img src=""smiley.jpg"" alt=""smiley""/>
            Dispalying Image and text
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is little different view to this problem, but it is really simple, without any additional styles.

Comment: putting `<img>` inside `<h2>` is not a good job. It's better instead to  change `display` property of the `<img>` to `inline-block` like in my answer

Comment: Yes, `inline-block` is also possible solution, what I'm writing is more "native" usage of HTML, Inline blocks are used as inline. You can see, that I don't need any other style property.

Comment: as I mentioned putting `<img>` inside `<h2>` is not a good practice. You'd better not doing it

Comment: Why? I know, that there are plenty of situations, where is `inline-block` the best way, but in this case? Could you explain for me why this is "not a good practice"? In problem such this - I don't see an advantage of your solution

Comment: content of an <h1> tag should be "phrasing content", which includes <img> tags as well and thus it is not invalid, but as I said it's not a good practice because it has SEO drawbacks. You may google it for more information

Comment: Could you recommend some articles for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83216/discussion-between-kamienok-and-trix).

Comment: Please ask in the community if you need information and stop spamming comments section

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

```html
<div style="float:left">
  <img style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle" src="http://www.smilys.net/lachende_smilies/smiley7702.jpg" alt="smiley" />
  <div style="display:inline-block;font-family:Calibri">
    <h2>Dispalying Image and text</h2>           
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to put your image to the left and the text to right you are doing well just assign the `float:left` style to the image instead of the main block like:

```
string html= @"<div>
        <img src=""smiley.jpg"" alt=""smiley"" style=""float:left""/>
        <div style=""float:left;font-family:Calibri"">
            <h2>Displaying Image and text</h2>           
        </div>
    </div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the expected output by placing image in one div and text in one div and both the div in one div. It worked:)
Like,

```
<div>
<div><img></div>
<div>text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a table.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <img src="smiley.jpg" alt="smiley"/> </td>
        <td> Displaying Image and text </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```